# Entremets vs dessert

Tags: vocabulaire, synonymes, alimentation

According to Larousse, "[entremets](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/entremets/30052)" is "plat sucré, chaud ou froid, que l'on sert entre le fromage et les fruits ou comme dessert." and "[dessert](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dessert/24639)" is "dernière partie d'un repas" or "mets sucrés qui le composent". I cannot see a difference between both definitions when they mean a sweet plate served after the main course. Is there any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several differences.

***Entremets*** literally means "between courses" while ***dessert*** etymologically means what is eaten during the *desserte*, the end of meal *service*. Consequently, an *entremets* wasn't a *dessert* (or at least not **the** *dessert*), being necessarily followed by some other dish.

Nowadays, the number of courses served in an average meal (typically 3 or 4 like *entrée*<sup>1</sup>, *plat*, *fromage*, *dessert*) is quite reduced compared to what it used to be in the past in the upper class society.

The usage of eating *entremets* has dropped too but many delicacies that used to be served as *entremets*, especially the sweet ones,  have kept this generic name and are logically served now as *desserts*.  They are essentially small and often soft individual dishes, like *crèmes*, *mousses*, *flans* and the likes while bigger pastries like a *tarte*, a *buche* and other things that are cut in parts or slices are not called *entremets*. Raw fruits and *plateau de fromage* are not considered *entremets* either.

Finally, there is a wide difference in usage, *dessert* is commonly used while *entremets* is rarer and more expected to be used in a *gastronomie* context.

Google Ngram shows a significant difference in written documents. I suspect it would be even wider if done from an oral French corpus.
 [image]

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Beware that the English ***entrée*** is a false friend, its French meaning being *starter*.</sub>

Comment: On savait vivre à l'époque, on prenait 2 desserts :-)

Comment: @LaurentS.Ou plus, si affinités ;-)